# Dynamic MongoDB collection names with Grails

Tags: mongodb, grails

I am using the [MongoDB Gorm Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) and now would like to create collections with dynamic names with it. As these collections can have *any* name, I can't create domains for each of them.

So I created a placeholder domain and before storing data in it, I tried changing its table name as follows:

```
DomainName.mapping = {
    table "thisIsTheNewName"
}
```

However, this obviously does not work. How can I accomplish dynamic collection names instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I took in the meantime was using [Gmongo](https://github.com/poiati/gmongo), a wrapper API around the MongoDB driver which is very similar to the command in the MongoDB shell.